# Inline en Django para 3 relaciones dependientes

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, django-admin, panel-de-administracion

Tengo 3 modelos en django. Y quiero que en el admin a partir del Modelo del que todo parte poder modificar los demas. Ejemplo: Tengo TCP, Contrato y Suplemento. Un TCP tiene varios contratos, y un contrato tiene varios Suplementos. Desde la vista de admin de TCP puedo agregar los nuevos contratos, pero no los suplementos.

```
class TCP(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Contrato(models.Model):
    tcp = models.ForeignKey(TCP, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Suplemento(models.Model):
    contrato = models.ForeignKey(Contrato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import TCP, Contrato, Suplemento

class SuplementoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Suplemento
    extra = 1

class ContratoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Contrato
    extra = 1
    inlines = [SuplementoInline]

class TCPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ContratoInline]
class ContratoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[SuplementoInline]

admin.site.register(TCP, TCPAdmin)
admin.site.register(Contrato)
admin.site.register(Suplemento)
```

[image: En el punto 3 deberia estar los suplementos pertenecientes a cada uno de los contratos]

Comment: En el punto 3 deberia ir la relacion con los suplementos pertenecientes a cada contrato